# How can you dynamically format a string with a user-provided template and slice of parameters in Go?

Tags: string, go, replace

I have user-provided format strings, and for each, I have a corresponding slice. For instance, I might have `Test string {{1}}: {{2}}` and `["number 1", "The Bit Afterwards"]`. I want to generate `Test string number 1: The Bit Afterwards` from this.

The format of the user-provided strings is not fixed, and can be changed if need be. However, I cannot guarantee their sanity or safety; neither can I guarantee that any given character will not be used in the string, so any tags (like `{}` in my example) must be escapable. I also cannot guarantee that the same number of slice values will exist as tags in the template - for example, I might quite reasonably have `Test string {{1}}` and `["number 1", "another parameter", "yet another parameter"]`.

How can I efficiently format these strings, in accordance with the input given? They are for use as strings only, and don't require HTML, SQL or any other sort of escaping.

Things I've already considered:

- `fmt.Sprintf` - two issues: 1) using it with user-provided templates is not ideal; 2) Sprintf does not play nicely with a number of parameters that doesn't match its format string, adding `%!(EXTRA type=value)` to the end.
- The `text/template` library. This would work fine in theory, but I don't want to have to make users type out `{{index .arr n}}` for each and every one of their tags; in this case, I only ever need slice indexes.
- The [valyala/fasttemplate](https://github.com/valyala/fasttemplate) library. This is pretty much exactly what I'm looking for, but for the fact that it doesn't currently support escaping the delimiters it uses for its tags, at the time of writing. I've opened an issue for this, but I would have thought that there's already a solution to this problem *somewhere* - it doesn't feel like it's that unique.
- Just writing my own parser for it. This would work... but, as above, I can't be the first person to have come across this!

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Maybe you should get a step back and explain what problem you are trying to solve with a user provided template (which by the way sounds like a security nightmare to me).

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Sure. Not all users have access to this - it's supposed to be only people with an idea what they're doing. Saying the slice was user-provided was a slight simplification: I need to use a regex to match over a string, and then the FindStringSubmatch output is my slice here (I'm cutting off key 0). I want to enable these trusted users to build a string from the submatches - so they might put in `b<1>ns` and the regex might be `/t(ea)/`, which would have expected output `beans`.

Comment: Again: why? What actual product do you want to solve?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg That is, in this case, the actual product :) I'm performing these searches on a large quantity of text, and then presenting the user with the relevant matches, formatted with their custom template.